# Is it possible to user EditorFor for class (not primitive types)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have class User

is it possible to use Html.EditorFor(a => a.User) so it will render correctly my html structure
Currently I have partial view like:

```
@model User
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LastName)
</div>
```

But I want to use something that when I pass the object inside EditorFor it would render html correctly if the User class would be nested dipper.

Comment: Let me know if my question is not clear

Comment: If I'm getting you wrong, look on google for `EditorFor complex type` and you'll get a bunch of examples. In short, you can do that, but you have to define a view with the template to be used.

Comment: Could you point some link for this. I can't find good links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, like Claudio said. You just need to define a View in the folder Views/Shared/EditorTemplates with the name User.cshtml. Then when you use the EditorFor method it will use that template.
I did a quick Google search and this came up : [asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/)

He basically says the same thing.